# How can I turn "Object Browser" to "Metadata" for "Go to definition" in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, go-to-definition

Before installing Resharper, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Click for `Go to definition`, Visual Studio 2010 uses to `Metadata`. After the install `Resharper`, when I try to first time <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Click, `Resharper` asked me with popup where I want to go, I click `Object Browser` for testing. Now I want to get back this setting, but in `Resharper`, there is only one option for this;

> ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Search & Navigation and turning
>   off or on Go to declaration on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ Left click in editor

[image: Resharp options]

But If I turned off this setting, It doesn't take back this setting to `Metadata`. It still goes to `Object Browser`. I don't want to reset all keyboard shortcuts because I use all other Resharper's shortcuts. How can change only this setting ?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Under **ReSharper > Options > Tools > External Sources**, select **Default Visual Studio navigation** (or "Navigation to Sources" for a wider set of navigation options incl. decompilation and fetching stuff from symbol servers)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone has this issue in VS2012?

I just fixed it with `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`

- select "Visual C# 2005"
- under "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme".
- Then click 'Reset'.

This was infuriating, hope it helps someone else. Worked for me with VS 2010 perfect.