# Visual studio c++ project go to definition opens object browser instead of going to source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have seen the following questions and tried all of their answers:

- [Visual Studio Go to Definition (F12) opens Object Browser instead of Code View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150021/visual-studio-go-to-definition-f12-opens-object-browser-instead-of-code-view)
- [How can I turn "Object Browser" to "Metadata" for "Go to definition" in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046933/how-can-i-turn-object-browser-to-metadata-for-go-to-definition-in-visual-s)

Namely that I have tried:

- Cleaning the project and deleting all generated project files
- Resetting all of the keyboard mappings

**The difference in this question from the previous listed is the following:**

1. It is a C++ project, not c#, there are no references and no .NET version.
2. I have not installed nor do I use the *ReSharper* program.
3. I have tried checking out the same code and solution in a separate directory, and the problem no longer occurs (but still occurs in the original after a clean checkout)
4. This started today, and I am unaware of an event that could have caused it. I have not installed any new plugins or similar. The only thing that has happened recently was that yesterday I installed some NUNIT references into a C# project that is in the same solution.

Since the other posts listed above did not list explicit details about the problem, **this is a detailed description of what is occurring**:

1. I try to go to definition on an object (or go to declaration), with either F12 or the right-click menu:
   [image]
2. Instead of going to the source of this (ie the `HeartBeat` class) it will show in the symbol search a list of possibilities:
   [image]
3. All of these references open the object browser window instead of going to the source:
   [image]

**How can I revert the behavior of visual studio to normal?**

Comment: This sounds like something to submit under Help->Send Feedback in VS and then watch the response page.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, if i want a solution next year, then sure. As in the question i could solve this by checking out new, but that is not very satisfying for me, or anyone else that runs into this problem.

Comment: So you know, at the worse case, you can always reset your VS completely by `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`

Comment: @DeanSeo, I didn't know that. You should make an answer out of it. Also it worked, so definitely add that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the OP mentioned, `/resetuserdata` will definitely bring your Visual Studio back to *normal* as follows:

```
devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

although this is not the *fundamental* solution.

This kind of weird situation can occur especially when you run multiple **Visual Studio** at the same time, and you changed a few configurations only on one of them.

That's because **Visual Studio** tries to share the same `.vssettings` and the file is over-written every time it exits, to keep `.vssettings` to have the newest configuration sets you made at all times - the definition of *the newest configuration* is the one the last **Visual Studio** that you closed has.

Therefore, the configuration change that you think you've made might not be the one your **Visual Studio** is running on.

To prevent this from happening, you could make your `.vssettings` *Read-Only*. 
Then every time you close it, your VS will complain about it, but you can keep your customized configuration safe. (Which, I agree, is sort of ugly though)